# angular-cli ng server errors on start up

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli

I have installed angular-cli and am attempting to 'ng serve' an Angular project created via "ng new [BLAH]FrontEnd", but I am getting those errors:

pastebin : http://pastebin.com/QB1D5PsF

What is going on. When I navigate to http://localhost:4200/ i see :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/"(…)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `npm start` instead `ng serve` to run the server with http://localhost:4200/

Comment: I also had to install node v6.9.1 because it did not work with node 7.0.0

Comment: I had version 6.6.x and then installed v6.9.1  but with npm start or ng serve I get the same errors

Answer (score 1):

try this

Update your angular-cli file present in the root directory with this

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
      "port": 4200
    }
  }
```

add this to your package.json

```
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve"
```